How to get windows to open a Minecraft server on startup
So far I've tried task scheduler directly which didn't work. I figured I can right a .bat file to start my server as follows.
"start java -jar "C:\Users\{username}\Documents\Minecraft server\server.jar"
If i click this .bat file it runs the server no problem. But if i use task scheduler to run this .bat file, it opens cmd and outputs Starting net.minecraft.server.main (normal) then it closes cmd (not normal). If i click the .bat file it outputs the same but then starts outputting everything the server does and stays open.
I've changed most settings in the task scheduler and they don't seem to have any effect.
I do have it set to open only when user is logged on, but my user doesn't have a password and manually running this task doesn't work.
Why does task scheduler not do the same thing as clicking it?
Is there some other easier way I can accomplish starting my server with Windows?

You might want to look up steps for how to run minecraft java as a windows service. The task scheduler action should be C:\path\to\java.exe and arguments: -jar "C:\path\to\server.jar" (using start or a separate .bat file is unnecessary). That said, it sounds like it is launching the server - check whether there's something in the server.log file that it's complaining about

I checked the logs, there is nothing from current time stamp at all. And i found the paths and input them like you said. Same exact result. Does the task scheduler end tasks after they've been started? Is there something I could add to my bat file that would keep it open? I also googled exactly what you said and just got a lot of result for how to setup a server, which isn't really useful.

Does the task work if you check the box to "run with highest privileges"? You can force a cmd window to stay open by setting the task to run cmd.exe with arguments /k "C:\path\to\java.exe" -jar "C:\path\to\server.jar". The /k there keeps it running once the process ends, but the reason it's closing is because the server stopped - likely a separate issue

I found the solution to this problem. Minecraft's Server.jar files rely on their environment to run properly. They create and read from files in the directory or folder they are located in. Task scheduler was just running the start.bat in java's directory. Minecraft servers require you to edit a text document agreeing to the eula before they will run.This is why my cmd window was closing; because I hadn't agreed to the eula.txt file that was in java's directory.
I don't know if this is the best solution but it works.
I created a start.bat file that says as follows:
CD /D \path\to\server\directory
java -jar "C:\path\to\server\directory\server.jar" 
pause

CD changes the directory to where it should open the server.jar file
Then I specify I want java to open a specific jar file.
Honestly I don't know what pause does or if its necessary, its just one of the many recommendations I found online.
Task scheduler is set to run this start.bat file when my computer powers on with a 5 minute delay. I did check the box "run with highest privileges".
